# Why does the Feign client custom configuration structure not meet this way?

Tags: spring-boot, feign

I am using `feign client` in an application with `spring boot` version `3.1.4`

I made a configuration definition for the `feign client.`

*Configuration class*

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FeignConfiguration {

  
   @Bean
   public Decoder feignDecoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters) 
   {
      //bla bla
   }

   @Bean
   public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
      //bla bla
   }

}
```

*Feign Client*

```
@FeignClient(name = "", url = "")
public interface FeignClient {
   //some methods
}
```

If I define it as above, it can find the relevant configurations without defining the configuration. However, I want to define a new feign client and I want this to be a new configuration. I am writing a second feign configuration class for this.

*Second Configuration class*

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecondFeignConfiguration {

  
   @Bean
   public Decoder feignDecoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters) 
   {
      //bla bla
   }

   @Bean
   public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
      //bla bla
   }

}
```

*Second Feign Client*

```
@FeignClient(name = "", url = "", configuration = SecondFeignConfiguration.class)
public interface SecondFeignClient {
   //some methods
}
```

While I'm waiting for my second feign client requests to work based on the configuration I gave, the feign configuration works based on the configuration (the one I defined first).

In the configurations I made for Feign client
If I do not use the `@Configuration` annotation, it works as I want and I have to specify `configuration = "...configuration"` for all `feign clients` I use.

Why does it happen this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/):

> A central concept in Spring Cloud’s Feign support is that of the named client. Each feign client is part of an ensemble of components that work together to contact a remote server on demand, and the ensemble has a name that you give it as an application developer using the `@FeignClient` annotation. Spring Cloud creates a new ensemble as an `ApplicationContext` on demand for each named client using `FeignClientsConfiguration`.

That means that Spring dynamically creates a separate `ApplicationContext` for each Feign client, which allows isolation between them. By declaring configuration using the `@FeignClient` annotation, you are telling Spring to use that configuration inside the `ApplicationContext` of that particular client. For that reason, it does not need to be annotated with `@Configuration`. However, if it is, it will become the default source for `feign.Decoder`, `feign.Encoder`, etc., when specified.

To conclude, use `@Configuration` on the class containing the default beans of `feign.Decoder`, `feign.Encoder`, etc. When there is a need for specific beans, create a separate class, without `@Configuration`, containing the beans that would override the default ones and declare it as the configuration in the `@FeignClient` annotation.

Comment: Thank u for answer. Yes, it creates a bean with configuration and all feed clients use it. If I define 1 feign configuration class and give it to the feign client as configuration = "feignConfig.class", will it create a separate bean for each one? What is the working logic here? Will this cause any additional performance problems? Let's say I have 100 feign clients, when I specify configuration = "BlablaConfig.class" for each one, it creates 100 different instances or does it take it from the existing instance?

Comment: I believe it will create a separate bean for each one. Therefore, you should find the most used beans and declare them as default by annotating the config class with `@Configuration`. In that case, if I am not mistaken, beans are inherited from your main application context and are not created in the client's context. Only put the specific beans in separate configuration classes.